# How should I route CMS urls alongside optional paramters / actions in route config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, content-management-system, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to add a basic CMS to an MVC website that uses a "url-formatted-string" as an ID for the CMS item.

I've spent many hours trying to meet the requirements set out below. But now I'm wondering "Is it even possible to do this?"

.

The first thing is that I would like to support "out of the box" MVC urls.

```
/news => NewsController.Index - I will set this to get the latest X items

/news/create => NewsController.Create

/news/edit/8 => NewsController.Edit - uses 8 as the id parameter
```

But I'd also like to support CMS items *in the /news/ section*, and for it to be filtered by text only URL.

```
/news/news-item-title => NewsController.Display - uses "news-item-title" as an id parameter

/news/search/search-term => NewsController.Search - uses "search-term" as a string parameter
```

Finally, I would like a default controller / action to pick up URLs with no controller or action defined. (And for this to accommodate forward slashes). So for example:

```
/services/consulting => CMSPageController.Index - defaults to CMSPage Controller and uses "services/consulting" as an id parameter

/about-us  = CMSPageController.Index - defaults to CMSPage Controller and uses "about-us" as an id parameter
```

Is all of this possible, or should I give up fighting route_config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I stumbled across the answer here:

[Dynamic Routes from database for ASP.NET MVC CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026441/dynamic-routes-from-database-for-asp-net-mvc-cms)

The answer is to provide a custom route constraint that checks the DB for existence of the CMS url.