# Adding a string to the url

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a app root :localhost/Product

I want to attach a string to my root url
localhost\stringName

stringName will be read frm config file and set to the end of url, followed by controller and action name
eg: localhost\Product\stringName\controller\Action
and stringName needs to be preserved throughtout the app with all redirects.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change default routing like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/stringName/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "DefaultPage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

From your RouteConfig.cs file. 
OR if you upgrade your application from mvc 4 to mvc 5 you can use the attribute routing you can read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx).

**Update:**

Try this in default route:

```
string stringName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stringName"].ToString()
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: stringName + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
);
```

Comment: The above route will not match because..my request doe not have stringName to begin with..it gets added on sessionStart in global.asax.

Comment: then you can implement IRouteConstraint like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026441/dynamic-routes-from-database-for-asp-net-mvc-cms

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

You need to do some research into custom url routes