# how to Change the url of page asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is not about url rewriting.

I want to change the url that is looking on browser.

For example the actual url is :

> localhost:57358/Admin/news.aspx?Id=24

I want it to look like

> localhost:57358/Admin/SomeContent....

to implement this I wrote a code in my global.asax but it is all about url rewiting.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sRequestedURL = Request.Path;
    string url = Request.Url.ToString();
    if (url.Contains("inner.aspx"))
    {
        int id = int.Parse(url.Split('=')[1]);
        ManageNews mn = new ManageNews();
        string title = mn.getTitleByNewsId(id);
        string targetUrl = "~/inner.aspx?Content=" + title;
        Context.RewritePath(targetUrl, false);

    }
}
```

please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't really get what you are trying to do but why not use  [Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) ([walk through here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) to achieve what you want. This way you can specify the Route in the start of your application and let asp.net handle it.

Quote from link -

> ASP.NET routing enables you to use URLs that do not have to map to specific files in a Web site. Because the URL does not have to map to a file, you can use URLs that are descriptive of the user's action and therefore are more easily understood by users.

e.g.

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("SomeContent",
        "Admin/SomeContent"
        "Admin/news.aspx?Id=24");
```

If you are trying to do something far more dynamic you may be able to follow the same path used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026441/dynamic-routes-from-database-for-asp-net-mvc-cms) (although that's for MVC, the logic remains the same) where the routing is configured through a database.