# How to create www.domain.com/product MVC route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to create a `http://www.domain.com/product` route.
It should look in the database for the product name and, if found, calls a controller and, if not, follows to the next route.

I've tried to create the route bellow, but I could not figure how to follow to the next routes in case `{shortcut}` product name is not found in the database.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "easyshortcut",
  url: "{shortcut}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Product" }
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via a route constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "easyshortcut",
    url: "{shortcut}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Product" },
    constraints: new { name = new ProductMustExistConstraint() }
);
```

Where `name` is your parameter name in the Product action of the `HomeController`.

Then implement the constraint:

```
public class ProductMustExistConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, 
        Route route, 
        string parameterName, 
        RouteValueDictionary values, 
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var productNameParam = values[parameterName];
        if (productNameParam != null)
        {
            var productName = productNameParam.ToString();

            /* Assuming you use Entity Framework and have a set of products 
             * (you can replace with your own logic to fetch the products from 
             *  the database). 
             */

            return context.Products.Any(p => p.Name == productName);
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

(The above was adjusted to this situation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026441/dynamic-routes-from-database-for-asp-net-mvc-cms).)