# ASP.Net MVC 5 Attribute routing configure at run time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using attribute based routing on my controller/action to define multiple URLs for the same action.

```
    [Route("MyHome")]
    [Route ("HomePage")]
    [Route("Home")]
    [Route("Home/admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

E.g.  Above route defines different URLs for the Index action, http://mysite/home, http://mysite/myhome, http://mysite/homepage, http://mysite/home/admin.

It works fine if I defines routes at code time, but my requirement is that I want to store in database and then retrieve same from db and bind at application initialization; Does anyone has any idea how to do same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried getting those urls from DB and assigning in `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes()` like in previous versions of MVC? This method is called from `Application_Start()` in global.asax.

Comment: `Attributes` are compiled as metadata into the assembly. By definition, you cannot edit attributes at runtime. If what you want to do is make a CMS that can be used to edit your routes at runtime, you will need to extend convention-based routing such as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31958586/181087).

Comment: I hope this reference can help anyone visit this topic! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026441/dynamic-routes-from-database-for-asp-net-mvc-cms